# Access passThrough from inside the respond statement in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using $httpbackend for some requests but I want to passThrough the request if certain condition is met:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('index').respond(function(method, url, headers) {
   if (security.currentUser == 'demo') {
        //how do I forward the request from here?

   } else {
       return [200, {somedata}, {}];
   }

}
```

The issue I have is that when the logged in user is "demo" all the requests should be through backend. Otherwise all requests should be normal.

I've tried to do it before setting conditions ($httpBackend.whenPOST....) but I can't access the currentUser, because the module.run is parsed before I have access to it.

Thank you!

Comment: There is a passThrough method on the object returned by whenGET: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.$httpBackend. I don't know whether you can do both for the very same path, but its worth a try to get hold of a reference to that object and then in your if block try to call .passThrough on it.

Comment: you usually use one or another. I'm trying to find something to forward the request from inside the respond method...

Comment: @Alexandru, This has been asked a long time ago. Did you find a solution for it?